# SyntaxError:" identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm getting that error being reported in firebug:

```
data = data + "&network=" + rowdata.network + "&10xx=" + rowdata.10xx;
```

can anyone help me how to fix this error.

Comment: error being reported due to `rowdata.10xx`. This is not a valid JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rowdata.10xx` is invalid JS. Dot notation access of properties uses identifiers and identifiers cannot start with a number. Either use a different property name:

```
rowdata.x10xx
```

or use square bracket notation, which lets you use strings instead of identifiers:

```
rowdata['10xx']
```